# Postgres optimizing select large subset

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, query-optimization

A query performs selection of product reviews (200M rows) which are filtered by their category. Each category is large so it may contain 200K unique product_ids.
When reviews (filtered by category) are selected - we have to process a large subset (200K rows) from a large table (200M rows).

Query example

```
explain analyze
select r.*
from (select distinct on (r.product_id) r.*
      from reviews as r
               join review_product_info as pi on pi.product_id = r.product_id
      where (pi.categories @> array['4572']::varchar(256)[] and r.publication_status in ('PUBLISHED'::review_publication_status_enum))
      order by r.product_id, r.likes desc, r.created desc) as r
order by r.created desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 21 rows only;
```

```
Limit  (cost=309701.99..309702.04 rows=21 width=899) (actual time=1594.890..1743.813 rows=21 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=309701.99..309785.83 rows=33534 width=899) (actual time=1577.723..1726.642 rows=21 loops=1)
    Sort Key: r.created DESC
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 39kB
    ->  Subquery Scan on r  (cost=1003.71..308797.86 rows=33534 width=899) (actual time=42.000..1686.791 rows=76098 loops=1)
          ->  Unique  (cost=1003.71..308462.52 rows=33534 width=3644) (actual time=41.995..1660.933 rows=76098 loops=1)
                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1003.71..306869.56 rows=637184 width=3644) (actual time=41.991..1596.437 rows=389237 loops=1)
                      Workers Planned: 4
                      Workers Launched: 4
                      ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=3.65..229974.75 rows=159296 width=3644) (actual time=17.795..677.632 rows=77847 loops=5)
                            Sort Key: r_1.product_id, r_1.likes DESC, r_1.created DESC"
                            Presorted Key: r_1.product_id
                            Full-sort Groups: 1071  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 55kB  Peak Memory: 58kB
                            Pre-sorted Groups: 208  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 106kB  Peak Memory: 167kB
                            Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 2096  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 58kB  Peak Memory: 68kB
                              Pre-sorted Groups: 437  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 140kB  Peak Memory: 173kB
                            Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 2080  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 63kB  Peak Memory: 65kB
                              Pre-sorted Groups: 350  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 101kB  Peak Memory: 109kB
                            Worker 2:  Full-sort Groups: 2047  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 59kB  Peak Memory: 68kB
                              Pre-sorted Groups: 357  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 217kB  Peak Memory: 240kB
                            Worker 3:  Full-sort Groups: 2038  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 65kB  Peak Memory: 74kB
                              Pre-sorted Groups: 396  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 104kB  Peak Memory: 113kB
                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..224299.36 rows=159296 width=3644) (actual time=10.717..508.580 rows=77847 loops=5)
                                  ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using reviews_categories_idx_test5 on review_product_info pi  (cost=0.42..25169.46 rows=20157 width=7) (actual time=10.606..130.585 rows=16227 loops=5)
                                        Filter: (categories @> '{4572}'::character varying(256)[])
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 24063
                                        Heap Fetches: 39028
                                  ->  Index Scan using reviews_product_id_published_idx on reviews r_1  (cost=0.43..9.41 rows=47 width=899) (actual time=0.008..0.021 rows=5 loops=81134)
                                        Index Cond: ((product_id)::text = (pi.product_id)::text)
Planning Time: 0.697 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 36
Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
Timing: Generation 7.050 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.928 ms, Emission 
56.984 ms, Total 67.961 ms"
Execution Time: 1745.852 ms
```

Either we use dedicated table for categories - or we inline categories in reviews table as an array column  - the result is the same - we have to scan large subset of table an reduce it later with distinct on, sort, limit.

Is there any chance that this type of query can be optimized?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and your index definitions as well as the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: The parallel query makes it rather hard to figure out where the time is actually going.  Could you post the plan collected after setting max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0?  Also, collect buffers usage data with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, and set track_io_timing=on first if possible (you need to be a superuser to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Sorts are costly and you're sorting **r.created desc** multiple times.  Removing what appears to be a redundant sort from the inner query should improve performance.